# How to export multiple Shapefiles to one KML file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml

As the title says, is it possible to export multiple Shapefiles to one single KML in QGIS (Similar to ["Map to KML" in ArcMAP](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012399))?

Comment: Do you want to have mixed geometries in the KML or are all geometries of same type?

Comment: I would like to have the option to use mixed geometries, yes.

Comment: Is it ok to create KMZ? KMZs are simply zip version of KMLs. "Map to KML" actually does the same, creates KMZ with multiple KMLs. BTW, if it is mixed geometries than it's best to put similar ones to single KMZs.

Comment: @blu_sr Having more than one KML file in a KMZ is not permitted as per the documentation. I tried it once to test the concept of multiple KML's in one KMZ. The idea of the KMZ is to store other media that is related to the KML file. [See documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives).

Comment: @danagerous, if I understand the steps described in that link, it didn't  say that more than one KML is not permitted. A KMZ can have any number of KMLs, but no KMZs. Try [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109555/nesting-kmz-files). I couldn't understand your difficulty, but I have been successful with this for a while. You may want to try the _"doc.kml"_.

Comment: @blu_sr The method you described will work and is still technically one KML file. The documentation clearly states "..and as long as there is only one .kml file." The method you described is using one KML to reference other KML files. It is not possible to simply dump file1.kml, file2.kml, file3.kml into the the KMZ.

Comment: @danagerous, glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the merge shape files to one tool. and then save as a KML. You can find this under Vector > Data management tools > Merge Shape Files to One.

Comment: PS: That tool merges shapefiles with the same geometry type.

Comment: The tool is now called "merge vector layers". As of QGIS version 3.10

Comment: In QGIS 3.30 and probably older this does not work fir different geometry types: "All layers must have same geometry type! Encountered a Line layer when expecting a Point layer."