# QGIS - export multiple layers with different geometry to one KML file

Tags: qgis, kml

I would like to export a few layers from QGIS to KML. So far I've managed to export it to the Geopackage format, but now I have to convert it.

Is there any option, which would allow me to select as many layers as I want and export them to one .KML file?

I tried MMQGIS plugin, but it exports one layer only

This thread explains that merging layers is required:

[How to export multiple Shapefiles to one KML file in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/how-to-export-multiple-shapefiles-to-one-kml-file-in-qgis)

However, as I said. I have layers with various geometries. Is it possible?

Comment: I think once you have different geometries you need to manually save them one by one using export features - just select the same KML to save to and change the layer name each time. Then when you drag the KML into QGIS it will show a dialog box with all the different layers in it.

Comment: No, this overwrites the file every time.